# Разделители на странице

Tags: html, css

Как сделать вот такие разделители `____________` только перевёрнутые.  И тонкие. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: ??? разделители, простите, чего?

Comment: этапять!!!

Comment: Вот такие `_________`, только перевёрнутые.

Comment: нарисовать.
вопросу -100500

Comment: |||||||| вот эти что ли?

Comment: +1 @johniek_comp

только он имел ввиду наверное перевернутые на 180' :)

Comment: скиньте картинку пожалуйста, а то не понятно

Answer (score 2):

[hr](http://htmlbook.ru/html/hr)